# Abrir app al detectar una geo Uri en Android, obtener valores

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-intent

Como se puede hacer que la app se abre. al pulsar un enlace desde el navegador web, chrome, firefox... un enlace de tipo `geo:...` [Geo URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme)

`geo:37.786971,-122.399677`

**Lo que tengo:**

Capturar cuando el usuario hace clic sobre un enlace `geo:...` en su navegador

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="geo"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Me falta procesar el intent desde mi app y separar los valores, latitud, longitud

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo de esta forma al recibir los datos en tu `Activity`:

```
 Intent bundle = getIntent();
 String dataReceived = bundle.getData().toString();

 //Elimina el esquema, y crea un array con los valores. 
 String[] latlong = dataReceived.replace("geo:","").split(",");
```

Obtiene datos latitud y longitud como valores tipo `String`:

```
 String lat= latlong[0];
 String lon = latlong[1];
```

Posteriormente puedes cambiarlos a `double` , mediante `Double.parseDouble()` :

```
 double latitude=  Double.parseDouble(lat);
 double longitude=  Double.parseDouble(lon);
```

Para obtener los valores:

```
latitude:  37.786971 
longitude: -122.399677
```